# redux typescript react-native-encrypted-storage

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux

// store.ts

```
export const createAppReducer = () =>
  combineReducers({
    system: systemReducer,
    posts: postsReducer,
  });

const reducer = createAppReducer();
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;

export const createAppStore = (initialState?: Partial<RootState>) =>
  configureStore({
    reducer,
    preloadedState: initialState,
  });
```

// utils.ts

```
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';

export const getStateFromAsyncStorage = () => {
  async function retrieveUserSession() {
    try {
      const session = await EncryptedStorage.getItem('user_session');
      if (!!session) {
        return {
          system: {
            userId: 'JSON.parse(session).userId',
            accessToken: 'JSON.parse(session).bmAccessToken',
            refreshToken: 'JSON.parse(session).bmRefreshToken',
          },
        };
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    return {}
  }

  const res = retrieveUserSession()

  return res;
};
```

// App.tsx

```
const state = getStateFromAsyncStorage()

const store = createAppStore(state);

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AuthStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I can't pass the state variable to the create App Store function, because getStateFromAsyncStorage() returns a Promise, how to make the Partial type preserved in state after calling getStateFromAsyncStorage()?

or tell me what to use to store jwt in react-native

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the **Promise** returning method using the **async** and **await** keywords.

To handle the **Promise** returned by an **async** function, you should use the **await** keyword when calling it.
Here's how you can call `getStateFromAsyncStorage()` with **async** and **await**:

***App.tsx:***

```
// Add imports here

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [store, setStore] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeStore() {
      try {
        const state = await getStateFromAsyncStorage(); // Use await to handle the Promise
        const appStore = createAppStore(state);
        setStore(appStore);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    initializeStore();
  }, []);

  if (!store) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AuthStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```